# How to import a regular javascript library with no type definitions in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

In particular, I'm trying to use ldapjs, which has only a partial TypeScript definition @types/ldapjs.

Because it's incomplete, I just want to use the methods in the ldapjs lib directly. Is that possible? All the tutorials/answers I find assume that there is a type definition module available. What to do when none is available?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to import it as follows:

```
import * as ldapjs from 'ldapjs';
```

Next you can instantiate it as follows:

```
let ldapjsInstance = ldapjs();
```

Then you can use any of its variables & functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to run the library through https://github.com/Microsoft/dts-gen which will attempt to create types for the library. It is not totally fool proof but it will generate the basic skeleton for the types